# print statement outside except block

Tags: python, try-except

```
import sys
lst = ['b', 0, 2,5]
for entry in lst:
  try:
    print("****************************")
    print("The entry is", entry)
    r = 1 / int(entry)
  except(ValueError):
    print("This is a ValueError.")
  except(ZeroDivisionError):
    print("This is a ZeroError.")
  except:
    print("Some other error")
print("The reciprocal of", entry, "is", r)
```

Print statement outside except block is getting skipped when program takes input as 2. But if I only give 3 elements in the list it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is because, the `print` statement is outside the for loop. So it prints for the last iteration of `entry` only.

Check this:

```
In [1340]: import sys 
      ...: lst = ['b'] 
      ...: for entry in lst: 
      ...:   try: 
      ...:     print("****************************") 
      ...:     print("The entry is", entry) 
      ...:     r = 1 / int(entry) 
      ...:   except(ValueError): 
      ...:     print("This is a ValueError.") 
      ...:   except(ZeroDivisionError): 
      ...:     print("This is a ZeroError.") 
      ...:   except: 
      ...:     print("Some other error") 
      ...: print("The reciprocal of", entry, "is", r)
****************************
The entry is b
This is a ValueError.
The reciprocal of b is 0.2
```

If you want it to print for every element, push the print inside the for loop:

```
In [1344]: import sys 
      ...: lst = ['b',0,2,5] 
      ...: for entry in lst: 
      ...:   try: 
      ...:     print("****************************") 
      ...:     print("The entry is", entry) 
      ...:     r = 1 / int(entry) 
      ...:   except(ValueError): 
      ...:     print("This is a ValueError.") 
      ...:   except(ZeroDivisionError): 
      ...:     print("This is a ZeroError.") 
      ...:   except: 
      ...:     print("Some other error") 
      ...:   else: 
      ...:     print("The reciprocal of", entry, "is", r) 
      ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
****************************
The entry is b
This is a ValueError.
****************************
The entry is 0
This is a ZeroError.
****************************
The entry is 2
The reciprocal of 2 is 0.5
****************************
The entry is 5
The reciprocal of 5 is 0.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your `print` is outside the `for` loop, it only gets executed after the last iteration of the loop, which is for the `5` value. You need to bring it into the loop, but put it into an `else` clause for the [`try`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), so that it only gets executed if an exception did *not* occur:

```
import sys
lst = ['b', 0, 2,5]
for entry in lst:
  try:
    print("****************************")
    print("The entry is", entry)
    r = 1 / int(entry)
  except(ValueError):
    print("This is a ValueError.")
  except(ZeroDivisionError):
    print("This is a ZeroError.")
  except:
    print("Some other error")
  else:
    print("The reciprocal of", entry, "is", r)
```

Output:

```
****************************
The entry is b
This is a ValueError.
****************************
The entry is 0
This is a ZeroError.
****************************
The entry is 2
The reciprocal of 2 is 0.5
****************************
The entry is 5
The reciprocal of 5 is 0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ['b', 0, 2, 5]
for entry in lst:
  try:
    print("****************************")
    print("The entry is", entry)
    r = 1 / int(entry)
    print("The reciprocal of", entry, "is", r)
  except(ValueError):
    print("This is a ValueError.")
  except(ZeroDivisionError):
    print("This is a ZeroError.")
  except:
    print("Some other error")
```

The print statement should be inside try block